# Best practice to initialize lookups in View Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an *Address* View Model and I used to initialize the list of countries from the database in the view model creation, however I realized that each time I create the ViewModel somewhere, the list of countries is retrieved from the db without being used, so I though of three ways to do accomplish this:

1. Add the Countries initialization to the *Address* View Model Constructor, very costly
2. Load the lookup from the controllers and then assign it to the view model and then load the view
3. Using lazy loading on the countries property, so the trip is made to the db only when the countries are required, something like this

   ```
       // Lazy loading
   [ScriptIgnore]
   private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> _Countries;
   [ScriptIgnore]
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { 
       get{
           if (_Countries.Count() > 0) return _Countries;
           else {
               using (var db = new AllegroDMContainer()) {
                   var rCountries = db.Countries.ToList();
                   _Countries = (from m in rCountries
                                select new SelectListItem {
                                    Text = m.Name + " (" + m.ISO + ")",
                                    Value = m.ID.ToString()
                                });
                   return  _Countries;
               }
           }
       } 
       set{
           _Countries = value;
       } 
   }
   ```

What do you guys think is the better approach here and the one that seems more natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Add the Countries initialization to the Address View Model Constructor, very costly

This is fine, assuming that you're passing a collection and not a DbContext.

> - Load the lookup from the controllers and then assign it to the view model and then load the view

This is the most common pattern I've seen.

> - Using lazy loading on the countries property, so the trip is made to the db only when the countries are required, something like this

This [couples the ViewModel to the DAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_science%29#Object-oriented_programming), which is a bad thing. Don't do this.

Comment: Agree. More over, the list of countries is something that will be used only sometimes (when creating and editing, I'd assume), so it should be retrieved only when needed and not every time the viewmodel is created